# Exchange SMTP address limit

Tags: exchange, smtp

i have an Exchange SMTP server but I want to enable this SMTP just for my email addresses (i don't want an open rely mail). How can I block all other recipients? Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information in this post, please elaborate. If you mean you want to configure an exchange server and accept only your emails this is the default configuration, if you add your domain to exchange as an accepted domain this is the only one it will accept.

Comment: Sorry, what is not enought? I want a smtp server linked to mx record to accept all email of my public domain. However i don't want to become an open mail-relay (to accept mx connection i had to remove the smtp autentication)... this is my goal.
Maybe I will need another virtual SMTP server with authentication for internal user to send email to all domains..

Comment: @Tobia It honestly sounds like you don't know enough about setting up an Exchange server.  See Alex Berry's answer.  If that's doesn't get you there, you're going to have to do some reading and learning on your own to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange server only delivers emails of domains it has listed in it's accepted domains.

Add your domain to this list and it should be fine, you can try and remotely connect to your smtp server and send email via another domain, it won't work.

If you want a more detailed description of how to do this you will have to be more specific, like what version of exchange you're running etc.